# I have tried to set up a free VPN on ubuntu, but failed

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I am trying to set up a VPN on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried OpenVPN, but it doesn't work for me. So I would like to know if there are some other way to do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do, how it failed, how you did it etc. "it doesn't work for me" doesn't tell us anything about your problem. What errors  do you get? What commands did you run? What VPN service are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Step 1 – Update your system. ...

*sudo apt update
*sudo apt upgrade

Step 2 – Find and note down your IP address. ...

ip a
ip a show eth0

Step 3 – Download and run openvpn-install.sh script. ...

wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh

chmod -v +x openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh
mode of 'openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
nano openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh
sudo ./openvpn-ubuntu-install.sh

Step 4 – Connect an OpenVPN server using iOS/Android/Linux/Windows desktop client.

Stop the OpenVPN server
sudo systemctl stop openvpn-server@server.service

Start the OpenVPN server
sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service

Restart the OpenVPN server after changing configuration options
sudo systemctl restart openvpn-server@server.service

Show status of the OpenVPN server
sudo systemctl status openvpn-server@server.service

Step 5 – Verify/test the connectivity.